# in-nest-sequence: sequence generator in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

`in-nest-sequence` is a sequence generator that takes a function and an initial value, and the return value of invoking the function on the current value is used as the subsequent value. For example, `(in-nest-sequence add1 0)` returns the sequence `(0 1 2 3 4 ...)`.

Recently, [soegaard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13154/soegaard) challenged me to write a `define-sequence-syntax` version of `in-nest-sequence`, that is, a macro-based version. I decided to give it a try:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax unstable/syntax))
(provide (rename-out [*in-nest-sequence in-nest-sequence]))

(define in-nest-sequence
  (case-lambda
    [(func init)
     (make-do-sequence
      (thunk (values identity func init #f #f #f)))]
    [(func . inits)
     (make-do-sequence
      (thunk (values (curry apply values)
                     (lambda (args)
                       (call-with-values (thunk (apply func args)) list))
                     inits #f #f #f)))]))

(define-sequence-syntax *in-nest-sequence
  (lambda () #'in-nest-sequence)
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [[(x ...) (_ func init ...)]
       (unless (= (syntax-length #'(x ...)) (syntax-length #'(init ...)))
         (raise-syntax-error 'in-nest-sequence
                             (format "~a values required" (syntax-length #'(x ...)))
                             stx #'(init ...)))
       (with-syntax ([for-arity (syntax-length #'(init ...))]
                     [(value ...) (generate-temporaries #'(init ...))]
                     [(y ...) (generate-temporaries #'(init ...))])
         #'[(x ...) (:do-in ([(f) func])
                            (unless (procedure-arity-includes? f for-arity)
                              (raise-arity-error f (procedure-arity f) init ...))
                            ([value init] ...)
                            #t
                            ([(x ...) (values value ...)]
                             [(y ...) (f value ...)])
                            #t
                            #t
                            (y ...))])])))
```

I'm a complete noob at using `define-sequence-syntax`, so I appreciate any and all style, performance, and/or general feedback about my code. (See [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936344/13) for some usage examples.)

Comment: The error `(for/list ([x (in-nest-sequence 42 0)]) x)` can be improved if a `(procedure? func)` test is inserted before `make-do-sequence` is called. Also: I am a bit torn about removing the one-value case. I am not 100% sure the optimizer can produce code that works equally well from the multiple values case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases where the the user follows the syntax and the function returns and receives the correct number of values, this works fine.

It is a good principle to catch errors as early as possible.

Consider this example:

`(in-iterate add1)`

Here the user supplies a function `add1` that has arity 1, but supplies no arguments. This will eventually lead to an "result arity mismatch;" error, when `add1`. This error can be caught earlier in using `procedure-arity` to check that enough init values are supplied. The error message presented to the user can be "expected 1 initial value, but received 0".

In the `*in-iterate` consider: `[(x ...) (_ func init ...)]` .
Here the number of bound identifiers (the `x`s)  must be the same as the number of init expressions. If they are not, a `raise-syntax-error` with `stx` as the source of the error can be used.

An example that should be a syntax-error (and not a runtime error):

```
(define (add1/2 x y) (values (+ x 1) (+ y 2)))
(for/list ([n     10]
           [(x y) (in-iterate add1/2 0)])
  (list x y))
```

The name of the construct is a bit off. In `in-list` and `in-sequence` we have the pattern `in-noun`, so that suggest `in-iteration` might be better. However `iteration` is a bit vague. Maybe one `in-nested-sequence` or `in-nest-sequence` based on the name used in Mathematica? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html

Comment: Wow, that's awesome feedback. Thanks! For checking that `(x ...)` and `(init ...)` are the same length, I guess one possible solution is to use a `syntax-case` fender/guard. Am I just checking whether `(= (length (syntax->list #'(x ...))) (length (syntax->list #'(init ...))))` or is there a better way?

Comment: I would use the same expression to the lengths. You could add a fender - and then add a new case to handle the error. When reading code I have a tendency to overlook fenders (and thus make mistakes). So I might be tempted to add the error checking directly to the existing clause - but that's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Turns out that `(syntax-length stx)` is in `unstable/syntax`. Hopefully it will be moved to `racket/syntax` at some point.

Comment: I don't know how to parse "I would use the same expression to the lengths", sorry. :-( BTW, I feel horrible about using `unstable/syntax` (which you just mentioned, lol), but apparently it provides `syntax-length` which simplifies the length-checking code a little. ;-)

Comment: to compare the lengths :-)

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and edited the question with the new code. (I've removed the single-binding variant for the macro, since it just results in too much code duplication.) Enjoy!